# Can't get the deluge interface to show through traefik2 even though working in local

Tags: docker, traefik, deluge

This is my traefik and deluge `docker-compose` file.

I am expecting `https://deluge-tv.$DOMAINENAME` to show the deluge interface.
When I use my local network 192.168.1.23:8113 it works as expected (192.168.1.23 is the local IP of my NAS which hosts all the docker images)

I have the same setup with other docker images for other services and everything works as expected.

What am I missing ?

```yaml
version: "3.7"

########################### NETWORKS
networks:
  traefik2_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik2_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge

########################### SERVICES
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:v2.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: # CLI arguments
      - --global.checkNewVersion=true
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage=true
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
      - --entryPoints.traefik.address=:8080
      - --api=true
      - --log=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --accessLog=true
      - --accessLog.filePath=/traefik.log
      - --accessLog.bufferingSize=100
      - --accessLog.filters.statusCodes=400-499
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.defaultrule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik2_proxy
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=false
      - --providers.file.directory=/rules 
      - --providers.file.watch=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-gandi.acme.storage=/acme.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-gandi.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=gandiv5
    networks:
      - traefik2_proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8448
        published: 8448
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - /not/relevant:/shared
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      # HTTP-to-HTTPS Redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      # HTTP Routers
      # traefik
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.rule=Host(`traefik.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].main=*.$DOMAINNAME
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].sans=$DOMAINNAME
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.middlewares=middlewares-basic-auth@file
  deluge-tv:
    container_name: deluge-tv
    image: linuxserver/deluge:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      traefik2_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.16
    ports:
      - target: 58846
        published: 58847
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 58946
        published: 58947
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 58946
        published: 58947
        protocol: udp
      - target: 8112
        published: 8113
        protocol: tcp

    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    volumes:
      - /not/relevant:/not_relevant
    environment:
      - PUID=$PUID
      - PGID=$PGID
      - TZ=$TZ
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      ## HTTP Routers
      - traefik.http.routers.deluge-tv-rtr.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.deluge-tv-rtr.rule=Host(`deluge-tv.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - traefik.http.routers.deluge-tv-rtr.tls=true
      ## HTTP Services
      - traefik.http.routers.deluge-tv-rtr.service=deluge-tv-svc
      - traefik.http.services.deluge-tv-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=8113
```